# Updgrading TFS Explorer Custom Control from 2010 to 2012 - rendering differences?

Tags: tfs, custom-controls

We use TFS 2010 with developers having both VS 2010 and VS 2012.  We had created a custom control (both TFS Explorer and Web Access).  Since several developers are moving up to using VS 2012 I was updating the TFS Explorer custom control to 2012 as well, but have run into an odd issue dealing with how the two Team Explorers rendering the control.

The control is a windows form control which contains a dropdown list and a button (it does not extend the TFS specific dropdown).  There is also a label that appears in some cases, but for the most part when it renders in VS 2010 it looks like this:

See images at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/e3e254e1-7f56-495c-a3c1-e92bfe030102

The missing white boxes are alterations to the image to redact internal information only.

Note that you can see the full dropdown and the refresh button.  This control is compiled with autosize (grow and shrink) with the dropdown and refresh button docked so that when you resize the form it correctly resizes just fine.

For the migration to 2012 I created a new project, moved the control over and updated the references for the Work Item control and Work Item client to the 2012 counterparts.  Everything compiled correctly, and the controls work as expected; however, they render poorly.

See images at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/tfsworkitemtracking/thread/e3e254e1-7f56-495c-a3c1-e92bfe030102

Note that the control is simply too wide.  It cuts off the refresh button completely and a bit of the dropdown is also cut off.

When I resize the window in VS 2012 it also scales "correctly" but it is cut off always in the same place.

The control itself is set up the same way between the two versions, literally all I did was reference the newer TFS related assemblies and recompiled, then deployed to my local 2012 folder to get it to pick it up.  Both 2012 and 2010 are pointed to the same TFS 2010 process template.  It just appears that the two render the controls different, or are basing the autosize on different values.  Is this a bug or some setting I'm not dealing with?

One option for me is to just set the control to a specific size, but I'd rather not do that.  Can someone give me a hint as to why these are rendering differently?

**UPDATE**: In playing around with this is appears that the control is simply sized too large.  In VS 2012 it has about 20-30 pixels more space given to it than it does in VS 2010, so when it autosizes it is too big, but then something in the rendering is cutting it off.  When I moved the inner controls to provide an empty space on the right of my control then they come into view; however, I've also noticed that as I enlarge the window and then attempt to shrink it back down the control simply doesn't get smaller anymore even though the autosize is set to shrink and grow.

**UPDATE**: I've posted this to the Connect site since it might be a bug in Studio. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/781607/updgrading-tfs-explorer-custom-control-from-2010-to-2012-rendering-differences

Comment: For those interested I provide a reproduction sample to Microsoft.  They evaluated it and, while not coming out and saying it was a bug, just advised that I rewrite the 2012 control using WPF.

Comment: You have been a member almost for 4 years on stackoverflow. You have almost 200 answers. And this is the only question you had asked so far. But there is no answer. Not even comment. What a bad luck Mike!

Comment: LOL, thanks. ON connect they responded that there was a difference in how it was handled and no, they weren't going to fix it.